# Deleting a thumbnail from a ListView using an ImageList. File locked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview, .net-4.0, imagelist

I have a `ListView` that is displaying an `ImageList` by using the following code:

Note: I am using an XML to get the individual images into the ImageList.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pictureList.Count; i++)
{
   Image temp = Image.FromFile(pictureList[i].InnerXml.ToString());
   Image img = temp.GetThumbnailImage(120, 120, null, new IntPtr());
   imageList.Images.Add(img);
}
```

When I go to delete an item I use the following code:

```
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);// This deletes said node from the XML
doc.Save(xmlpath); // This then saves the updated XML document

imageList1.Images.Clear(); //Clear ImageList1

refreshThumbnails();  //Function that Regenerates thumbnails (without deleted image)

File.Delete(picturePath);  //Deletes the image
```

The above code only executes when the image is not shared in another XML.

I have tried adding a timer, removing the specific item from the `ListView` directly and clearing the `ImageList`. They all intermittently give a generic IO error saying that a file is locked.

The only thing consistent is that if it is the last image in an album, it will always throw the same I/O error.

My main question is how to avoid this error? I can delete about 75% of the time, the other 25% it gives me a "file locked" error.

=============================================

I think I found my answer.

When loading the images with:

```
imageList.Images.Add(img);
```

I forgot to dispose the image afterwords. Since I refresh the thumbnail to reflect the latest XML status, it locks the last image it loads. So whenever I delete the last image (AKA the only image in a list) I am trying to delete a locked file.

Does this seem right? I am very new to C# and I am just glad it is working for now.